# NSArrayController "Content set" bound to NSTreeController issue

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller, nstreecontroller

I have an NSOutlineView bound to a NSTreeController and a CoreData Datamodel. 
NSOutlineView displays his data properly.

A NSTableView's cell values bound to a NSArrayController, displaying data from CoreData.
NSTableview displays his data properly too.

The Datamodel has a relationship between data for NSOutlineView and NSTableView

When I try to bind NSArrayController's "Content set" to NSTreeController.selection.name 
to display all items related to the NSOutlineView selection I get this error:

Cannot create NSSet from object Untitled of class NSCFString
(Where "Untitled" is the value of NSOutlineViews node)

And no data in NSTableView is displayed.

Everything setup in IB - does anyone has a hint for me to get this working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind the `NSArrayController`'s `Content Set` to `NSTreeController`, it's `Controller Key`  to "selection" and then the `Model Key Path` should be the relationship name, which I would hope isn't "name".  Then in the TableView you bind the column(s)'s value to the `NSArrayController`, with `Controller Key` being "arrangedObjects" and `Model Key Path` the property "name"

Comment: I did it this way but I figured out that I simply messed up the data model relationships.